# How to set programmatically password toggle state for TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I am using TextInputLayout from Google material design library (version 1.4.0-alpha02).

If I set this property in the XML:

```
app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
```

A button is displayed to toggle between the password being displayed as plain-text or disguised.

Now if I try to do the same programmatically, as reported in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setEndIconMode(int)) I call

```
myTextInputLayout.endIconMode = END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE
```

The button appears correctly, but tapping it has no effect.

I tried to play a bit with all the methods and I found out that doing this:

```
myTextInputLayout.clearOnEndIconChangedListener()
myTextInputLayout.endIconMode = END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE
```

makes the button work: the content of the editText actually changes from plain-text to disguised, but the button stay the same. The icon is supposed to change depending on the state.

This is the layout I am using:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/myTextInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:textColorHint="?android:textColorSecondary"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@drawable/text_input_stroke_selector"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
    app:endIconTint="?android:textColorSecondary"
    app:errorIconDrawable="@null"
    app:hintTextColor="?android:textColorSecondary">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Any idea?

Comment: It should work. can you post your layout?

Comment: Hi @GabrieleMariotti I updated the question with the layout.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. The only change is about boxStrokeColor that works with a color instead of a drawable but it should be related to your issue

Comment: Thanks @GabrieleMariotti can I ask you which version of the library did you use?

Comment: 1.3.0 and 1.4.0-alpha02

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks for the help. You are right, on a normal scenario works fine. I dug deeper and find out that the part that was setting the endIcon was called twice, which normally is not a problem, but in this case seems to be a problem because it is controlled by a flag contained in a LiveData. Not sure why is happening